# Redirect URI mismatch error with LinkedIn OAuth in Django Allauth on localhost

Tags: django, oauth, localhost, linkedin-api, django-allauth

I am developing a LinkedIn sign-in feature for my Django application using Django Allauth. Everything seems to be configured correctly, and authentication works fine up until the point where LinkedIn attempts to redirect back to my application. I'm working on localhost and I'm receiving an error stating "The redirect_uri does not match the registered value" after attempting to authenticate with LinkedIn. I'm using http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/linkedin/login/callback/ as my redirect URI during tests in my local environment.

Question:
Could anyone provide some guidance or help on this matter? Does LinkedIn allow redirect URIs to localhost for development testing, or is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: Most of the post is well-written. The bottom paragraph, which starts as: "Ensuring the redirect URI in my LinkedIn application matches exactly with what I'm using in my local environment. ...". Are these actions you did yourself or are you guiding potential answerers here on how to help you? If you meant the letter, then please remove that text. You can use the text yourself to see whether you provided all the relevant information in your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show us how you have configured the provider and the redirect URL in your code?